# EF Association Tables in multi-tenant DB

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have run into a serious limitation of EF and need help.

Here are my tables:

**Table: Company**

- TenantId INT  PK
- CompanyId INT PK
- other columns...

**Table: Role**

- TenantId INT PK
- RoleId  INT PK
- other columns...

Here is the association table:
**Table:  CompanyRoles**

- TenantId  INT  PK
- CompanyId INT  PK
- RoleId INT PK

This issue I am having is in my mapping class, I'm trying to avoid modeling the association table to keep things simple, everything worked earlier but we added `TenantId` everywhere.

Here is the C# mapper code for `Company`:

```
  this.HasMany(t => t.ContactRoles)
      .WithMany(t => t.Companies)
      .Map(m =>
      {
        m.ToTable("CompanyContactRoles");
        m.MapLeftKey("TenantId", "CompanyID");
        m.MapRightKey("TenantId", "RoleID");
      });
```

EF blows up because I am using `TenantId` on both sides of the many to many mapping, here is the error:

One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

## TenantId: Name: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'TenantId' is already defined.

Does EF not support multi-column KEYED association tables?  The TenantId in the association table is used for 2 relationships but it seems to want a dedicated TenantId for each relationship, that isn't going to happen as those columns must exist in the actual table.

Comment: While I'm not familiar with this case, it is possible you have to explicitly mention the tablename, as in `MapLeftKey( "CompanyRoles.TenantId", "CompanyID" )`?

Comment: hmm, @BobKaufman i never tried that...

Comment: that didn't work, it throws SQL exception for unknown column.